# Jenkins Not detecting changes on parent repo

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

I have a question . I am using Jenkins 1.6 as a CI tool and mercurial version 3.7.3 . In the build process, I have two WAR files DEVICE and REST . My issue was, Jenkins was detecting changes only when there is a change in device and war files. I mean only on the child repo's and It is not detecting If I make any changes on the parent Repo . Is there any flaw in my Build process.. ? Please find the attached image . 
[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have two build triggers one parent and one for the child, if either one    changes the build should trigger. So this means that you will require to
enter two different git repository paths.

Comment: Hello Wayne, Thanks for your help. Can I know how to create two build triggers. I am new to jenkins . So it would be great If you help me out .